# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE on client while creating simple spring boor rmi app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-remoting

I am creating spring boot applicating using RmiServiceExporter on server and RmiProxyFactoryBean on client.When i start server everything seems ok, i get

```
[main] o.s.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter: Binding service 'ServerServiceIF' to RMI registry: RegistryImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[localhost:1099](local),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
```

Then i start my client which is also spring boot app and my service interface on client is connecting to the adress on localhost.

```
rmi://localhost:1099/ServerServiceIF
```

But when i try to call method of this interface i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.isCorbaConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.isConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:174)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.isConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptor.java:283)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.doInvoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:260)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.auth(Unknown Source)
    at com.cw.client.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 9 more
```

Here are my server and client:

**ServerApplication.java**

```
package com.cw.server;

import com.cw.appif.ServerServiceIF;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class ServerApplication {

@Bean
ServerServiceIF serverServiceIF() {
    return new ServerService();
}

@Bean
RmiServiceExporter exporter(ServerServiceIF implementation) {

    // Expose a service via RMI. Remote object URL is:
    // rmi://<HOST>:<PORT>/<SERVICE_NAME>
    // 1099 is the default port

    Class<ServerServiceIF> serviceInterface = ServerServiceIF.class;
    RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
    exporter.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);
    exporter.setService(implementation);
    exporter.setServiceName(serviceInterface.getSimpleName());
    exporter.setRegistryPort(1099);
    return exporter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

**ClientApplication.java**

```
package com.cw.client;

import com.cw.appif.ServerServiceIF;
import com.cw.exceptions.AuthException;
import com.cw.models.User;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientApplication {

    private static User user;

    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean service() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactory = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiProxyFactory.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/ServerServiceIF");
        rmiProxyFactory.setServiceInterface(ServerServiceIF.class);
        return rmiProxyFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerServiceIF service = SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args).
                    getBean(ServerServiceIF.class);
            user    = new User("Denis","1234","e@mail.co");
            service.auth(user);
            System.out.println("User authed");
        } catch (AuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

My server service interface and implementation on server:

```
package com.cw.appif;

import com.cw.exceptions.AuthException;
import com.cw.models.User;


public interface ServerServiceIF{

    boolean auth(User user) throws AuthException;

}

package com.cw.server;

import com.cw.appif.ServerServiceIF;
import com.cw.exceptions.AuthException;
import com.cw.models.User;

import java.util.List;

public class ServerService implements ServerServiceIF{

    static List<User> clients;

    @Override
    public boolean auth(User user) throws AuthException {
        clients.add(user);
        System.out.println("hi");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Heres my thoughts:

1)Maybe its because interface which im using is exactly the same on client and server, but client cant find class, because path is different?

2)When im debugging my client service->h->advised->targetSource ->targetClass is null. Is it ok? I will upload screenshots of my project structure and this variable in debug below.

[server structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi8Li.jpg)

[client structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlm8e.jpg)

[debugging client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5r3P.jpg)

Comment: You are using Java 9, you will have to add the Corba classes to the classpath.

Comment: Oh, i see. But as i understand, i just can`t use corba exception. I`ll add it and update post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. After adding corba to classpath, I found out that class User has to be `Serializable`. Adding `implements Serializable` and `serialVersionUID` fixed the problem and now everything is working.

Comment: How did you add corba to classpath?